# Is there a way to make Visual Studio ignore a specific vcpkg library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcpkg

I have a VS solution that contains two projects: **A.dll** and **B.lib**. **A.dll** depends on **B.lib** and also **C.lib** which is provided by my vcpkg repository.

The problem is that my vcpkg repository also contains a version of **B.lib** and the linker will include both the vcpkg **B.lib** and my local **B.lib** which leads to multiple defined symbols.

Since I need vcpkg to provide the **C.lib** dependency, I can't disable it for the project completely. I need the linker to ignore the vcpkg version of **B.lib**.

Comment: Is the version of B.lib different from the B.lib in A.dll? I suggest that you could try `#pragma comment(linker,"/nodefaultlib:aaa.lib")`.

Comment: This didn't appear to work for me. Does anybody know if this is possible, short of removing a library from VCPKG?

Comment: Just rename your lib name of B.lib!